# DAO vs RuntimeExceptionDao ORMLite Android?

Tags: android, dao, ormlite

What is the difference between **DAO** and **RuntimeExceptionDao** using **Ormlite-Android**? When to use one and not other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is *very* clear on the difference. A `Dao` (see [docs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html)) refers to

> Database Access Objects that handle the reading and writing a class from the database

Whilst a `RuntimeExceptionDao` (see [docs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/RuntimeExceptionDao.html))

> Proxy to a `Dao` that wraps each `Exception` and **rethrows** it as `RuntimeException`. You can use this if your usage pattern is to ignore all exceptions. That's not a pattern that I like so it's not the default.

They do the same thing, apart from the `RuntimeExceptionDao` will only ever throw a `RuntimeException` - For more info on ORMLite, please refer to the ORMLite docs as they are actually really helpful.